# Use RLIKE in Mysql - with empty or all Values

Tags: javascript, mysql, rlike

Is there any way to use RLiKE in Mysql in order to get all records?

I use this script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT day FROM gestionsaasco WHERE month RLIKE '';
```

But this is the server answer:

```
Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp
```

Note: I'm not use "like '%%', because there are more than 8 filers and each one could be many values in my array, so I convert the array into string in order to use it in mysql, like this:

```
const DataMonth  = req.body.data.month.map(value => value.value);
const month = DataMonth.toString().replace(",","|");
/* DataMonth looks like [05,06,07] */
/* month looks like 05|06|07 */

const months = await pool.query('SELECT DISTINCT day FROM gestionsaasco WHERE month RLIKE ?',[year])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RLIKE is looking for a regular expression

Empty string is `'^$'`  (no text between start and end

And all text `'.*'`